# vimscript copy paste variable

Tags: perl, copy-paste, vim

i have the following command in my .vimrc:

nmap gtb texecute "!perl /home/hermann/hi.pl ".shellescape(getline('.'), 1)

it executes a perl script and sends whichever line the cursor is over, to it.
how do i send to the script whatever is in the copy-paste buffer instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no single 'copy-paste' buffer in Vim, there is a set of named registers instead. You can get the contents of a register using getreg function - it has a single argument, register name. For example, use this to get the contents of a default yank/paste buffer:

```
getreg('0')
```

Comment: i turn my line to: nmap gtb texecute "!perl /home/hermann/hi.pl ".getreg('0')<enter> and the outcome is miscellaneous errors, depending on what's in my paste buffer. any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: nmap gtb :execute "!perl /home/hermann/hi.pl ".getreg('0')<CR> works for me.

Comment: @Hermann Ingjaldsson: why did you get rid of the `shellescape()` call? Of course you would get various errors.

Comment: because i didnt know any better. its better now but the perl script is printing the buffer content to the terminal and there it seems to fail on all kinds of different letters. it works on really simple sentences only containing normal letters. its like the register isn't just a text string but that it actually interprets whats in the buffer somehow. for instance, # is always converted into some sentence. is there any way to prevent this and only get the text of the buffer?

Comment: :execute launches an Ex command, so you'll need to escape Vim's special symbols. To avoid this, use system function: `:call system('perl /home/hi.pl '.shellescape(getreg('0')))<CR>`

Comment: @zeuxcg special symbols will get escaped by `shellescape` if you pass it `1` as a second argument: `shellescape(@", 1)`. By the way, why you suggested `getreg('0')` instead of `getreg('"')`? And why you do not write `@0` instead of using `getreg`?

Comment: @ZyX, " is updated by deletes, which may or may not be what the OP wants; I did not know about @.

Comment: @zeuxcg Yes, but @0 is not default yank/*paste* buffer, only yank.

Answer (score -2):

you can use the 'normal' function to paste the clipboard contents.

```
   function MyPastingFunc()
     "paste from clipboard
     normal! "+p
     "do more stuff 
   endfunction
```